# How to integrate third-party authentication(except facebook and twitter) in ios native app in Parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com, I'd like to integrate third-party authentication( except facebook and twitter), Sina weibo for example, I found no way to achieve this:

After my app authenticated by Sina Weibo App, I got an uid and an access token, First I query the uid in Parse data, if not found, I signup with a random username and  password, then my PFUser.currentUser() is not nil

while what if the uid exist? how to become a user now?

Here is my code:

```
func upsertUser(userInfo: ISSPlatformUser!){


    var query = PFQuery(className: "TokenStorage")
    query.whereKey("wb_uid", equalTo: userInfo.uid())
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in

        println(objects)

        if( objects.count == 0 ){
            println("this account not register ")

            self.newUser(userInfo)
        }else{

            println("already register")

            var tokenData = objects[0] as PFObject
            var user = tokenData.objectForKey("user") as PFUser
            var accessToken = userInfo.credential().token()

            println("accessToken:" + accessToken)
            println("user:")
            println(user)


            if  accessToken != tokenData.objectForKey("accessToken") as NSString {
                tokenData.setObject(accessToken, forKey: "accessToken")
            }
            tokenData.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (succeed: Bool!, error: NSError!) in
                if succeed! {
                    var sessionToken = user.sessionToken

                    println("sessionToken:")
                    println(sessionToken)

                    println("currentUser:")
                    println(PFUser.currentUser() )

                    PFUser.becomeInBackground(sessionToken, block: nil)



                }

            })



        }
    })

}

func newUser(userInfo: ISSPlatformUser!){
    println("new user ")
    var user = PFUser()

    var s = NSMutableData(length: 24)!
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, UInt(s.length), UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(s.mutableBytes))
    let base64str = s.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)

    user.username = "wb_" + userInfo.uid()
    user.password = base64str
    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (succeed: Bool!, error: NSError!) in
        if succeed! {
            var ts = PFObject(className: "TokenStorage")
            ts.setObject(userInfo.uid(), forKey: "wb_uid")
            ts.setObject(userInfo.credential().token(), forKey: "accessToken")
            ts.setObject(user, forKey: "user")
            var acl = PFACL()
            acl.setPublicReadAccess(true)
            acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false)

            ts.ACL = acl


            ts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
        }
    })


}
```

The session token is nil that can not become a user, which make me frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to sign up your user with a password you know. For instance, to create a unique password per user, you can encode the userInfo.uid() with a constant string you keep safe.

This way, if you find that a user is already registered, you can log in with username/password.

Let us know if you found a better solution.